# Creating multiple labels, from cells of Excel sheet, on a form

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have code from this website:

```
Sub addLabel()
UserForm4.Show vbModeless
Dim theLabel As Object
Dim labelCounter As Long

For labelCounter = 1 To 3
    Set theLabel = UserForm4.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", Cells(i, 1) & labelCounter, True)
    With theLabel
        .Caption = "Test" & labelCounter
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 50
        .Top = 10 * labelCounter + 10
    End With
 
Next
End Sub
```

This code is in a worksheet module.

It works, but when I open the form once more, it shows nothing. So, when I press f5, the form loads, but is blank.

Comment: In what circumstances does it "works perfectly"? This code needs to be run somehow, it is not in the initialization event.

Comment: What I mean by "Runs it perfectly" is when I run the macro it shows labels and Form with desired labels, but once i reopen all gone!!
I think you are right, I ahve to put it in UserForm_Click() event
But, I am not able to do it
Can u please help me out?

Comment: Why do you want to do this on the fly? Why not just add your labels to your existing userform?

Comment: I want to use all this to existing userform only. But when i put labels, the labels will be like Label1, Label2 etc. I want those labels with caption from the text in A1, A2 and so on. One time exrcise only. Then I will use this form to export my data to excel sheet

Comment: This gives me desired result (command button is in Form itself, but once more when I open Form the default value written back, like Label1, Label2 etc.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Label1.Caption = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text
Label2.Caption = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Text
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in `userForm4` events , so there wont be any answer by run nothing.
your code is a module and when you open module `Sub addLabel()` and run it , it will be show what you want.
you can write any code on `UserForm_Click()` or whatever you need to run on form events.